# How can I show random products in Magento homepage?

Tags: magento-1.9, home

How can I show 12 random products in my Magento 1.9.0.1 homepage every time it is reloaded?

Comment: You don't want to do this. Your customers want a solid view on the page, so when they show their friends/partner/whoever the page, the product they want to show is still there. So I recommend to not have "total randomness"!

Comment: Good point, thank you. I don't want show only random products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll write some psuedocode for you:

```
While(size($productarray[] <= 12)){
    $randomId=generaterandomid();
    if($randomId->getproduct()){
        $productarray[]=$this->load($randomId);
    }
}
```

...

```
foreach($productarray[] as $product){
    ...
}
```

This will generate random ids (you can constrain it however you want) that will be used to populate your product array.  Then a simple foreach will put them all onto the page however you want.

Answer (score 2):

Add in home page

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list_random" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" num_products="12"}}
```

control columns add `column_count="number"`

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list_random" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" column_count="4" num_products="12"}}
```

Comment: Thank you so for your reply. This works partially because it shows only one product and hides (I don't understand why) the rest of the content block (like text and images).